# Is it possible to make closed skscene?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Is it possible to make closed `SKScene`, so that, for example, an `SKSpriteNode` moving over the boundary on the right, would immediately appear on the left (or its part, which has gone beyond the boundary) ? So that left and right boundaries of the scene were identified?

Comment: There is no scene wrapping unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is absolutely possible, both in SpriteKit, and programming in general.

There are two main ways to do something like this, but more, too.  Which is best for you is up to you and your game.

- Use Physics

Physics facilities in SpriteKit report contacts between bodies. If you have a frame around the world of your game (the screen, in this case), you can grab the information about the character when they contact the edge, and transform the velocity and position to the other side of the screen, as you desire, and play will continue.

- Use basic maths

Because it's just a matter of relative position, you could manually use maths to constantly check the position of the player relative to the edge of the screen. If and when the player exceeds your edges, you can transport their character to wherever you want on the opposite side, and impart velocity, rotation, etc as needed.

**ps:** if you want to read up on how to do this mathematically, search for tutorials and instructions on how to replicate an arcade classic game, "Asteroids", as it was (quite famously) the first game to feature this.

Comment: It is more complicated then this, you need to involve duplicate sprites to handle seeing the sprite on both sides of the world.  This also involves duplicate physics bodies, which starts becoming a pain.